# Vasicek Model Solving ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the textbook here https://academic.oup.com/book/43511/chapter/364184750 on the Vasicek Model.[image]

I don't understand why from 21.32 to 21.34 there was a change of sign on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

The change of sign is because $t$ is in the lower limit of the integrals, hence when you differentiate you get an extra minus sign.

Alternatively, you can switch the limits of the integral at the cost of a minus sign.

Comment: I still don't see it, could you elaborate?